# can different-time-zones/wrong-date-times mess up git merges and cause old bugs to show up again? (remote & teamwork)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

we have an app in production , which has a remote repository on Gitlab,

sometimes when we locally git merge , old changes overwrites new changes(without git saying anything or warn us) , and when we release a new version , some old and previously resolved bugs show up again.

does a remote repository supposed to calibrate date/times of local's? or we should do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Git commit timestamps are not used by the merge logic. Whatever is causing your issue, it's not due to the timestamps on the commits.